# JS. Как в массиве добавить к ключу значение

Tags: javascript, объекты, value, google-tabs

В **Google Tabs** перебираю значение в одной колонке и записываю номер строки в массив

```
for (i = 4; i <= LR2; i = i+3) {
    n = ss2.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    if (typeof myObj[n] == "undefined") {
        myObj[n] = i
    }
}
```

В итерируемом списке бывает так, что значения повторяются, я не хочу перезаписывать значение, ходу добавить. В общем хочу получить словарь, как в питоне, где ключ - текст из ячейки, а значения - все номера строк, в которых есть этот текст.
Но получается так, что идёт просто перезапись.
Я, наверное, неправильно гуглю, но особо ничего не смог найти про **key/value**.

Как к **key** добавить ещё **value**, в не перезаписывать **value**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 4; i <= LR2; i = i+3) {
    n = ss2.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if (typeof myObj[n] == "undefined") {
        myObj[n] = [i];
    } else {
        myObj[n].push(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: блин, я пробовал и пушш и адд, выдавало ошибку :((

Comment: увидел в чем разница

Comment: Большое спасибо, Игорь!

Comment: @dutik Пожалуйста. Успехов.